# TeamCity server doesn't see a running agent

Tags: intellij-idea, continuous-integration, teamcity, build-server

We have several virtual machines distributed among several data centers. Each VM has its own rebooting schedule with different timezones. The problem is when VM with TeamServer is rebooting and other VM with buildAgent is running build then after rebooting the server is not able to find the agent. It's shown as disconnected. Problem is definitely in scheduling but I haven't found it in the logs. I've found this in `launcher.log`

> [2012-09-09 10:02:06,356]   INFO - ldServer.agent.run.AgentRunner -
>   Agent process finished [2012-09-09 10:02:06,379]   INFO -
>   ldServer.agent.run.AgentRunner - Agent has exited with code: 30
>   [2012-09-09 10:02:06,382]   INFO - ldServer.agent.run.AgentRunner -
>   Launcher is exiting
>
> ...
>
> [2012-09-10 12:53:02,826]   INFO -
>   ldServer.agent.run.AgentRunner - Mon Sep 10 12:53:02 BST 2012 ==>
>   Start launch

What does `Agent has exited with code: 30` mean?
Does that mean that build agent was killed at that time or it forced its suicide for some reason?